# Adding label to dx-text-box control

Tags: html, angular

`<div class="dx-field"> <dx-text-box #userLogin label="userName" [(value)]="login" placeholder="UserName or email" width="100%"> <dx-validator> <dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="UserName Required"></dxi-validation-rule> </dx-validator> </dx-text-box> </div>`   How to add a associate label to the dx-text-box control

I have created a login page by giving username and password under textbox control. Now lighthouse showing me the error of. Forms do not have associate labels. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to review how `label` works in HTML, [see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

Here is an Angular example from [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/forms):

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="power">Hero Power</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="power" required>
    <option *ngFor="let pow of powers" [value]="pow">{{pow}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

However, please read the HTML content I shared above, otherwise you will have more problems. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Thank you Lorenzo. And also, Can you please give me a solution for my recent question.

Comment: I see it is closed. Nothing I can do about that.